# Presupuestador con PHP y jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estoy creando una pagina para un producto donde el usuario puede personalizar el diseño el mismo, colocar el color, el nombre, y a su vez tiene que el mismo ir armando el presupuesto todo en la misma web, Actualmente todo lo he conseguido faltando solo el presupuestador ya que funciona como un "carrito de la compra" donde el va personalizando y añadiendo a la lista el problema es que este tiene que ir sumando, o restando segun el vaya agregando o quitando, Estoy estancado aqui ya que no logro que el presupuestador vaya sumando/restando items segun el usuario vaya eligiendo.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <form name="bag_data" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF8">
        <h4>Order Details</h4>
        <fieldset>
            <ul id="item_" style="list-style:none; text-decoration:none; text-transform: capitalize">

            </ul>

        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="qty">TABS QTY</label>
            <br>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" disabled="" name="qty_item" value="" placeholder="QTY">
            <hr>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label style="font-size:16px; font-family:Arial; display:none" for="color"></label>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button style="display:none" id="button-carts" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-loading-text="Loading...">
                        <i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i>
                        Add to Cart
                        </button>
        </fieldset>
        <hr>
        <fieldset>
            <label>Cart items <i class=" fa fa-cart-plus"></i></label>
            <br>
            <!--                        12 Blue&nbsp;<a href="#"><i style="color: red" class="fa fa-close"></i></a>-->
            <ul id="first_tabs"></ul>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset style="display:none">
            <input type="hidden" id="id_bag" name="id_bag" value="">
            <input type="hidden" id="color_bag" name="color_name" value="">
            <input type="hidden" id="qty_bag" name="qty_bag" value="">
            <input type="hidden" id="" name="delete" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="price" value="">
            <input type="hidden" id="suma" name="suma" value="">

        </fieldset>
        <field>
            <h2 id="total" style="font-size:25px" class="price-h">
                <span class="price-old">Total: $0</span>
            </h2>

            <!--                        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Check Out">-->
        </field>
    </form>
</div>
<script>

</script>
<script>
    $(".img-thumbnail").click(
        function (event) {
            $("#item_").html(
                '<ul id="item_" style="list-style:none; text-decoration:none; text-transform: capitalize; margin-left: -4em;font-size: 16px;"><li id="color_selected">'
                + $(this).attr("alt") +
                '&nbsp&nbsp<i style="color:green; font-size:12px" class="fa fa-check"></i></li></ul>');
            $("label[for=qty]").text($(this).attr("alt") + " TABS QTY");
            $("input[name=id_bag]").val($(this).attr("alt"));
            $("input[name=color_name]").val($(this).attr("alt"));
            $("input[name=qty_item]").prop("disabled", false);

        });
</script>
<script>
    $("input[name=qty_item]").change(function () {
        $("label[for=color]").text($(this).val() + " " + $("#color_selected").text()).fadeIn(500);
        $("input[name=qty_bag]").val($(this).val());
        $("#button-carts").fadeIn(800);
        //PRICE COOKIE
        var price = 4.99;
        budget(price, $(this).val());
    });
</script>
<script>
    if ($("#id_bag").val() !== "" && ($("#color_bag") !== "")) {
        $("#button-carts").prop("disabled", false).click(function () {
            if ($("input[name=qty_bag]").val() >= 1) {
                $("#button-carts").prop("disabed", true);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "bag.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    data: $("form[name=bag_data]").serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#first_tabs").append(data);
                        $("form[name=bag_data]")[0].reset();
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert("error");
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
</script>
<script>
    //COOKIE BUDGET
    function budget(price, increment) {
        $("input[name=price]").val(parseFloat(Math.round(price * increment)));
        //$("#total").html(parseFloat(Math.round(price*increment)));
    }
</script>
```

Código PHP

```
$BAG = new bag($_POST["qty_bag"], $_POST["color_name"], $_POST["id_bag"], $_POST["delete"]);
class bag{
    public function bag($num_tabs,$color,$id, $delete){
        $this->num_ = $num_tabs;        
        $this->color_ = $color;
        $this->id_ = $id;
        $data = preg_replace("[\s+]", "", $this->id_);
        $message = $this->num_. " " . $this->color_;
        if(isset($_POST["delete"]) && (empty($_POST["delete"])) && ($_POST["delete"]==="")){
            echo "<li class='bag-list' id='$data'>$message&nbsp&nbsp<a id='$data' href='#'><i style='color:red;font-size:12px' class='fa fa-close'></i></a></li>";
            echo "<script>
            $('#$data').click(
                    function(){
                      $(this).remove();  
                    });
            </script>";
        }else{
           exit;
        }
        if(isset($_POST["price"]) && $_POST["price"]==0){
            $this->budget = $_POST["price"];
            echo "<script>
            $('#total').text($this->budget);
            $('input[name=suma]').val($this->budget);            
            </script>";
            $this->budget = 0;
            echo "ok";
        }else{
            $this->budget = $_POST["price"];
            echo "
            <script>
            var operation = document.getElementById('suma').value
            var suma = parseFloat(operation+$this->budget);
            $('input[name=suma]').reset();
            $('#total').text(suma);
            </script>
            ";
            $this->budget = 0;

        }      
    }
    private $num_, $color_, $id_, $budget;
}
```

El único problema es la logica, es que al agregar un item este de un presupuesto, al agregar otro se sume el presupuesto que tenia anteriormente, y si lo elimina que automaticamente le reste al presupuesto, como una calculadora se podria decir

Answer (score -1):

Por ejemplo, puedes crear una variable en javascript y le vas sumando/restando los items del presupuesto.

Lo que no entiendo es porque usas Php, lo que has hecho se puede hacer todo en Javascript/Jquery??